# Microsoft Intune filter by primary user field

Tags: filter, collections, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I wanted to create a configuration profile for Windows computers to lock their screens after 10 minutes afk for non-managed devices (without Primary User assigned).

Threfore, I have created the configuration profile to lock any screen. To include only those devices without primary user assigned I have been reading about [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/filters) and about [creating filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/filters-device-properties) on Microsoft documentation but there is not out-of-the-box `device.primaryUser` property on the "device" entity.

I kept reading and found the [`device` development documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/intune-data-warehouse-collections#devices) and I didn't find anything related to the primary user there...

So, how can I apply the filter only for devices that don't have primary user assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use these resources to assign the last logged in user as the primary user
[https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/blob/master/ManagedDevices/Win10_PrimaryUser_Set.ps1](https://svdbusse.github.io/SemiAnnualChat/2020/03/21/Changing-Intune-Primary-User-To-Last-Logged-On-User.html)

And here

[https://svdbusse.github.io/SemiAnnualChat/2020/03/21/Changing-Intune-Primary-User-To-Last-Logged-On-User.html][1]](https://svdbusse.github.io/SemiAnnualChat/2020/03/21/Changing-Intune-Primary-User-To-Last-Logged-On-User.html%5D%5B1%5D)